# how to create relationship in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, relationship, pymongo, database

how to create relationship in mongodb?
I create foreign key between two collection users and connection_log.
how to find from connection_log to users collection from relationship?
please guide me or shown to me with example.

Answer (score 3):

There is no concept of JOIN in MongoDB.  There are no "foreign key" declarations.  There is no referential integrity check.  Get used to it.

You either model your relationships directly in the document:  One to Many as an array in the One...

```
// users document
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("536bc13f20c26cde11a40001"),
    "userName" : "Mudshark"
    "connection_log" : [ 
        {
            "startTime" : ISODate("2014-05-09T17:40:24.307Z"),
            "endTime" : ISODate("2014-05-09T18:40:24.307Z")
        },
        { 
            "startTime" : ISODate("2014-05-01T17:00:00.000Z"), 
            "endTime" : ISODate("2014-05-01T18:00:00.000Z")
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("536bc13f20c26cde11a40002"),
    "userName" : "Tailhook"
    "connection_log" : [ 
        { 
            "startTime" : ISODate("2014-05-08T23:32:12.992Z"),
            "endTime" : ISODate("2014-05-08T01:32:12.992Z") 
        }
    ]
}
```

Or you leverage ObjectId to "relate" 2 documents in different collections.

```
// users document
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("536bc13f20c26cde11a40001"),
    "userName" : "Mudshark"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("536bc13f20c26cde11a40002"),
    "userName" : "Tailhook"
}

// connection_log document
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("aefe13f20c26cde11123453"),
    "user_id" : ObjectId("536bc13f20c26cde11a40001"),
    "startTime" : ISODate("2014-05-09T17:40:24.307Z"),
    "endTime" : ISODate("2014-05-09T18:40:24.307Z")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("aefe13f20c26cde11125511"),
    "user_id" : ObjectId("536bc13f20c26cde11a40002"),
    "startTime" : ISODate("2014-05-08T23:32:12.992Z"),
    "endTime" : ISODate("2014-05-08T01:32:12.992Z")
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("aefe13f20c26cde111212ab"),
    "user_id" : ObjectId("536bc13f20c26cde11a40001"),
    "startTime" : ISODate("2014-05-01T17:00:00.000Z"),
    "endTime" : ISODate("2014-05-01T18:00:00.000Z")
}
```

Don't despair.  You'll be operating at "Web Scale":  http://youtu.be/b2F-DItXtZs

Comment: mercy,but how to use of these ways for fetching data?

Comment: and how to set ensureindex for startTime in connection_log?